# Adding/removing MKCircle is choppy/slow, trying to simulate resizing

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

So the `radius` property of `MKCircle` is read-only, necessitating that any resizing be done via removal of the original `MKCircle` from the map view, and adding the new one.

To make things smoother, I am adding the new circle to the map view before removing the old one.

The process of resizing is smooth enough in the iOS simulator, but testing on a real device results in choppy animation, and some temporary "blocking" artifacts of the MKCircle's color as it resizes.

Anything I can do to make it smoother?